# Repair - help identify IC component 711 ?734 207M

Tags: power, identification, components, repair

This is ROLLER GRILL PIS30 induction plate. It died when "normal (non-inductive) pot was placed on top of it". Photos show the blown part, but my search-fu failed to provide any results about what it might be.

I can see the following:

`711 ?734 207M`

The middle part is probably `1734`.

[image: Device nameplate]

[image: Photo of board]

[image: Close-up of component location]

[image: Close-up of component (detached)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an [ACS711](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/sense/current-sensor-ics/zero-to-fifty-amp-integrated-conductor-sensor-ics/acs711) current sensor.

For future reference / searching tips, I found it by Googling "711 qfn" (as it's a QFN package) -- this was the first answer.